# Jekyll cannot find include files from within a collection

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, liquid

Sorry if this has been answered before, I've tried searching and haven't found anything.

I am using Jekyll 3.8.5 (the version supported by github pages). I have an include file `youtube.html` which is located inside my jekyll `_includes` directory. I am trying to reference the file from a file within a collection and it is just erroring - stating that it could not find the file within `[collection]/_includes` which is clearly wrong and should just be `_includes`.

Any idea how to fix the path so it can correctly find the include file?

You can see my implementation here: https://github.com/dtsn/jungleskipper/blob/feature/members/_members/jonas-brisbane.md

I did try this in jekyll 4 without a problem.

Comment: Except some links error on members pages, it works perfectly well locally with a github pages setup.

Comment: @DavidJacquel It works fine when I run it on Jekyll 4.0, but not on 3.8.5 I just get the following error - Liquid Exception: Could not locate the included file 'youtube.html' in any of ["/Users/daniel/Repositories/jungleskipper/_members/_includes"]. Ensure it exists in one of those directories and, if it is a symlink, does not point outside your site source. in jonas-brisbane.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running on MacOS beta, I switched back to the non-beta channel, reinstalled Ruby and Jekyll and I'm not getting the error any more. Wierd one...

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue comes from the fact that you set post as a collection in your _config.yml

Remove

```
posts:
    title: Posts
    output: true
    layout: post
```

Comment: That didn't actually make a difference, thanks though.

Comment: Glad you succeeded! Weird issue though